# How i can access particular object of an image on touching that object

Tags: objective-c

i am using an imageview and want to access particular object of an image ,however in an image on imageview contains many objects . after touching particular object ,that whole object must be reflect on another imagview.

Comment: what type of object are you talking about on image view?

Comment: suppose there is a image in that car,bike,scooter,cycle(objects) are mentioned. now i touch on the car, and want create only car's image  on another imageview .are you getting it?